# syntax for rejecting items in array with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

I have this working for my array:

```
my_arr.delete_if{|x| x=~/achievement\..*?/}
```

it deletes all strings in the array that match the pattern `achievement.`. Is there a similar one-liner to do the reverse (only accept strings that contain `achievement.`?

Comment: There is nothing in your search that requires using a regex, and, as is, it will slow your code. Use `x['achievement.']` instead because a substring search is faster than an unanchored regex.

Comment: @TinMan,  This was simply one example. I have several dozen of these most of which do require regex, although you are correct, this one does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [Array#keep_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-keep_if) instead of #delete_if

```
my_arr.keep_if{|x| x=~/achievement\..*?/}
```

Comment: Nice, much better than what @Yu came up with.

Answer (score 2):

No need to modify the regex, you can use `Array#keep_if`.

```
my_arr.keep_if{|x| x=~/achievement\..*?/}
```

Comment: 7 seconds late. You're losing it, Yu. Even the spacing is the same.  Did you and @Robert have a mind-meld? Aside from that, I much prefer your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the better solution is definitely to use `keep_if`.

The OP asks whether there is a way to

> only accept strings that contain "achievement."

So yes, again not the best way but you could use negative lookahead: `(?!exp)`:

```
my_arr.delete_if{|x| x=~/(?!achievement\..*?)/}
```

A further alternative, still using `delete_if` is to use the "not equals matching" operator (thanks @Cary):

```
my_arr.delete_if{|x| x!~/achievement\..*?/}
```

Again, thanks @Cary, for pointing out that this is not pleasant logic to find in anyone's code so use `keep_if`

Comment: Why would you prefer that to simply `x !~ /achievement\..*?/`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland ahh, I was trying to think of the syntax for that, thanks! Added.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't suggesting that, as deleting if a condition is not true is a hair's breath from keeping if the same condition is true. It's the same as suggesting `reject` when `select` has already been proposed--it doesn't add anything. As to the lookaround, I don't see why one would consider that.